# Popover template option makes content disappaer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to add a custom class to a popover, so I tried using the template option on where `popover()` is being called. However, whenever I bring in the use of the template, I get a popover with a title and then no content. What outside thing could be breaking it?

js:

```
$(this).popover({
    template: '<div class="popover my-class" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>',
    placement:'right',
    trigger:'hover',
    title:'my title',
    content: 'hi'
});
```

If I take the template option out, it works fine.

Comment: You're missing the closing single quote after `'my title,`
EDIT: Ah, that was just an error typing it into SO. Are you able to provide the code for the page, so we can see if there are any conflicts, etc?

Comment: I suspect something is affecting the visibility of your title via CSS. As far as I can tell, there is nothing wrong with your popover options objector the template you've provided. http://jsfiddle.net/rk76LwL3/

Comment: Add a `trigger: 'click'` to your popover options object, so you can forcibly open the popover and inspect it in your browser's developer tools. My guess the title is there but hidden based on your custom class or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
    <a href="#" id="example" class="btn btn-primary" rel="popover"
   data-content="Popover example"
   data-original-title="Title">Click
</a>

<script>
$().ready(function(){
var Template = '<div class="popover my-class" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>';

    $('#example').popover({
        template: Template,
        placement:'right',
        trigger:'hover'
    });
});
</script>
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/14329/

Comment: Why are you putting the string into an array and then joining it? This is essentially just reposting the question as an answer.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, considering the only difference is that you took the OP's template string and placed it into an unnecessary variable. Although, I suppose they could be forgetting to put the code in the `domready` event, but considering they have it working without the template, that's probably not the problem either.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's working fine. I added some CSS to show that your custom class works.

Could you add some more of your code, perhaps there's something else preventing the content from showing up correctly?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ravvy/297ve4cj/

HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover">Toggle popover</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    template: '<div class="popover my-class" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow </div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>',
    placement:'right',
    trigger:'hover',
    title:'my title',
    content: 'hi' 
});
```

CSS:

```
.my-class {
    color: red 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I finally fixed it: I changed it the trigger to click and inspected the popover without setting a template. It turns out there was a `<div class="popover-inner">` after the `.arrow`. Once I included that in the template, the content showed up.